# How to calculate the height of a header in <body> tag?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

How do I calculate the height of a `<header>` tag from a `<main>` tag so that I can use the `calc()` function to calculate the rest of the screen space available to span a banner in its place.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- A Navigation Bar of some sorts -->
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="banner">
      <!-- Some text on the banner -->
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.banner {
  height: calc(100vh - /* Height of <header> */);
  background-image: url(some image);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Just an FYI... I'm designing for a project for college and for mobile specifically so this formatting will not span to desktop as I will change the styling for desktop and tablets

Comment: You will need JS for that.

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: Why not use `flexbox` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have time to learn JavaScript the easiest the thing to do is to give the header a fixed height. Than you can subtract the fixed height from the banner. It's not the most beautiful solution, but it works:

````
header {
  height: 80px
}

.banner {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  background-image: url(some image);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}```
````